# Datatable is not working in two conditions?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to keep the state of pagination even page is refresh in Datatable, and remove sorting of first and last column.

I have tried

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
"aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false },null,null,null,null,{ "bSortable": false }]} )
 stateSave: true
});
```

both above conditions (remove sorting of first, last column and pagination state ) are not working together but working separately.

please tell me how to implement both conditions.

Thank you.

Comment: May be this is the reason ..I found syntax error replace this within datatable "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false },null,null,null,null,{ "bSortable": false }],stateSave: true

Comment: you should have provide answer, so that i could mark it right and raise the points. It worked. thank you

Comment: i am very glad to hear that in SO...its ok..